# v-on:scroll event is not applying the scroll event to methods

Tags: vue.js

`v-on:scroll` is not working. I added it to a div and I have a method to do a console.log but it doesn't do that

```
    <template>
      <div v-on:scroll='handleScroll' class="homepage-section">
    content
    </div>
    </template>

methods: {    
    handleScroll(){
      console.log( 'ww')
    },
  },
```

Comment: It's hard to say without a minimal reproduction. Is the scrollbar visible on your div?

Comment: Yes, I added the @scroll on the parent div